# Create a function on the fly injecting local var values inside

Tags: javascript

I need to write functions on the fly while avoiding the use of global variables. They'll be 'connected' to event listener.

I currently have a function to create a connection. They receive:

- The object I want to connect
- Two variables: IDX and id I have to identify some element that I want to use.

This is my code so far:

```
create_fun = function (obj, IDX,id) { 
    var f = function () {document.getElementById(IDX+"_"+id).display = "block";} 
    obj.addEventListener('click', f,false);
}
```

This code runs OK. I see in the Chrome Event Listeners Panel the click event connected to the objected that I wanted.

**The Problem**: IDX and id are variables, and as they are not globals, they are undefined.

At chrome Eventlistener inspection I see:

> handler = function ()
>   {document.getElementById(IDX+"_"+id).display = "block";}

But, being IDX = "sec1" and id="3", I'd like to see :

> handler = function ()
>   {document.getElementById("sec1+"_"+"3").display = "block";}

Is this possible? How would I do this?

Comment: Huh? Where is `VAR1` and `VAR2` here? They are not in your sample at all.

Comment: `does not use VAR1 and VAR2 values but VAR1 and VAR2` - what's this?

Comment: If you define `VAR1` and `VAR2` inside `create_fun` then they should be available inside `MY_FUN` because `create_fun` is a closure. But it's completely unclear what you are trying ask here. Perhaps some actual code would help? Of course, every function in `MY_FUN` would share the same `VAR1` and `VAR2` and maybe that's your problem???

Answer (score 0):

The fix is given by Function constructor

```
var f = new Function ( "document.getElementById('"+IDX+"_"+id+"').style.display = 'block';" );
obj.addEventListener('click', f,false);
```

}